# react 2 similar routes overlap and causes only 1 to show

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<Route path={`/games/mods`} /> // 1st

<Route path={`/games/mods/files`} /> // 2nd
```

Here I have 2 simple routes that are relative/dynamic, I cannot add the 'exact' parameter to them because when a user clicks on a game the 1st path becomes like this `/games/mods/Halo` so if it's exact then it won't show anything... the problem is that when the user goes to `games/mods/files/Halo` the 1st route gets activated and the 2nd one gets ignored, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems like a silly answer, but worthy try. Just change the order might help you.

```
<Route path={`/games/mods/files`} /> // 1st

<Route path={`/games/mods`} /> // 2nd
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your routes like this:

**1st Approach**:

Try to wrap your routes inside `Switch` and change the sequence of your routes

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`/games/mods/files`} /> // 1st
  <Route path={`/games/mods`} /> // 2nd
</Switch>
```

**2nd Approach**:

Access `Halo` in your route `/games/mods/Halo` by writing your route like `/games/mods/:name`.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path={`/games/mods/files/:name`} /> // 1st
  <Route path={`/games/mods/:name`} /> // 2nd
</Switch>
```

Check out `Route Props` documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props